# Accessing JMX from Ruby without JRuby and Java

Tags: java, ruby, jvm, jruby, jmx

I am wondering if it is possible to access JMX (RMI) data without using JRuby and Java, purely from Ruby.

Comment: You can't do RMI without Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMI/JMX data is not available without Java.